# SSL Install on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate

I've been tasked with getting a new SSL installed on a website, the site is hosted on AWS EC2.

I've discovered that I need the key pair in order to connect to the server instance, however the client doesn't have contact with the former web master.

I don't have much familiarity with AWS so I'm somewhat at a loss of how to proceed. I'm guessing I would need the old key pair to access the server instance and install the SSL?

I see there's also the Certificate Manager section in AWS, but don't currently see an SSL in there. Will installing it here attach it to the website or do I need to access the server instance and install it there?

Answer (score 1):

There is a [documented process](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html#replacing-lost-key-pair) for updating the SSH keys on an EC2 instance. However, this will require some downtime, and must not be run on an instance-store-backed instance. If you're new to AWS then you might not be able to determine whether this is the case, so would be risky.

Instead, I think your best option is to bring up an Elastic Load Balancer to be the new front-end for the application: clients will connect to it, and it will in turn connect to the application instance. You can attach an ACM cert to the ELB, and shifting traffic should be a matter of changing the DNS entry (but, of course, test it out first!).

Moving forward, you should redeploy the application to a new EC2 instance, and then point the ELB at this instance. This may be easier said than done, because the old instance is probably manually configured. With luck you have the site in source control, and can do deploys in a test environment.

If not, and you're running on Linux, you'll need to make a snapshot of the live instance and attach it to a different instance to learn how it's configured. Start with the [EC2 EBS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSVolumes.html) and try it out in a test environment before touching production.

I'm not sure if there's any good way to recover the content from a Windows EC2 instance. And if you're not comfortable with doing ops, you should find someone who is.

Comment: I just informed the client I may not be the right person for this job, due to my lack of experience with AWS. I don't want to be the one who blows away their website when trying to switch instances etc. Thanks anyways!